# Flutter FlutButton Styling when disabled not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

here is my FlutButton :

```
         FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              disabledColor: Colors.grey,
              disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Text(
                "Connectez-vous",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: mobileWidth * 0.04,
                ),
              ),
             onPressed: () {
                if (RevendeurTemp != null) {
                  saveRevendeur(RevendeurTemp);
                  navigateToMainPage(context);
                }
                else {
                  print ("desabled") ;
                  null ;
                }
              },
            ),
```

when the button is disabled and click on it it prints "disabled" but the Style of the button is the same wither it is enabled or disabled .
[image: My Button image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the edited code below.

```
FlatButton(
      color: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
      disabledColor: Colors.black12,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Text(
        "Connectez-vous",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: RevendeurTemp == ""
          ? null
          : () {
              saveRevendeur(RevendeurTemp);
              navigateToMainPage(context);
            },
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

It is still in `enabled` state since it has an `onPressed` function in it.

That's why it doesn't turn to grey.

Try something like this,

```
FlatButton(
          ......
          child: Text(
            "Connectez-vous",
          ),
          onPressed: null
        ),
```

When `onPressed` becomes `null`, it becomes `disabled` state!

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/onPressed.html

Hope that solves your issue!